# RequireJS Optimer Ignore Plugins

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, arcgis

I am writing an app that uses a dojo api which is hosted. I'm writing the rest of my app using AMD to fit nicely with Dojo's amd loader. I want to use some of the AMD loading plugins that dojo provides, specifically dojo/i18n for translation/

Works great from the source but anytime I try to optimize the code, I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'normalize' of undefined." I understand it is trying to load the plugin and check for the normalize() but the plugin is only hosted and cannot be downloaded.

I would like this plugin to be ignored when optimizing the code and require the correct translation file at runtime.

Comment: Is the ["empty:" meta-path](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#empty) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this issue, in my case i had troubles to get things working with dojo/text.
To solve it try following:

1. Get the requirejs version of i18n on GitHub https://github.com/requirejs/i18n/blob/master/i18n.js
2. Include it to your project. Best is to place it in a subfolder which is not deployed. In my case its ./libs/build/i18n.js (don't worry, its only used for optimization and wont replace dojo/i18n)
3. Go to build.js (build is located in ./build.js) and add following item to paths:

   ```
     paths: {
        dojo: "empty:",
        dojox: "empty:",
        i18n: "./libs/build/i18n"
    }
   ```
4. Go to your index file where you have a require (or add it to dojo.config) and add a new alias:

   ```
   require({
        aliases:[["i18n", "dojo/i18n"]]
   }, 
   ["..."], 
   function(...){});
   ```
5. Replace every occurence of dojo/i18n!nls/strings.js in your app with i18n!nls/strings.js, so the alias will be actually used.

   ```
   define(["dojo/i18n!./nls/strings.js"], function (nls)
   ```

   replace with

   ```
   define(["i18n!./nls/strings.js"], function (nls)
   ```

After step 5 requirejs will recognize the requirejs-version of i18n and can actually call normalize. But your app will still use dojo/i18n because its hidden in an alias.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, this got me really close. After I optimize I still get a multipleDefine error for dojo/i18n (everything still works). I think this is because it comes packaged with the main API and adding the alias tries to define it again. I worked around this by removing the alias and switching the i18n! back with dojo/i18n! after I optimize the app in my build process.

Comment: I remember that i also had multiple defines. But i dont remember the exact solution. Check your resulting app.js if everything looks correct. Maybe try with build.js => optimize: "none" and check again. As long as the component dojo/i18n isn't defined twice, it should really work without workaround. (and maybe try dojoConfig = {async:false} as well...